# Linux Mint (Cinnamon, Muffin) set a keyboard shortcut where one of the keys is a mouse

Tags: linux-mint, keyboard-shortcuts, window, dconf

Linux Mint 17 Cinnamon Edition.

I want to create a keyboard shortcut involving the mouse. Specifically, I want to make it so clicking Alt, right-click, and dragging my mouse allows me to resize the current window.

I've gone to Keyboard > Keyboard shortcuts > Windows > Resize window > Keyboard bindings, and clicked on the default "Alt-F8" entry so that I can set a new entry, and tried to use my mouse while setting one, but it is not captured.

So I opened up `dconf-editor` and tried setting `org.cinnamon.muffin.keybindings.begin-resize` to `<Alt>Mouse2`, `<Alt>Mouse_2`, `<Alt><Mouse2>`, `<Alt><Mouse_2>`, `<Alt>Secondary`, `<Alt><Secondary>`, and none of these worked.

What is the "code" for the right mouse button for these keybindings? Where is the documentation for these keybinding "codes"? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This does not actually answer my *question* (I still do not know the keybindings syntax for a right mouse click), but this did solve my *problem*, so I'm leaving this here for anyone who stumbles across it in the future:

`gsettings set org.cinnamon.desktop.wm.preferences resize-with-right-button true`

Apparently there is a setting for holding alt, right-clicking a window and resizing it. The above command enables it.

Comment: You should actually leave it as a comment or even make different question, since `This does not actually answer my question`. The issue is that it shows this as a question with one unaccepted answer. As the unaccepted answers phenomenon is common these days, the ones, who know the answer may skip the question when they see it having 1 answer. 

I'm leaving it here as I'm struggling to find the solution just as you are.